# How to Save files to download folder using Storage Access Framework android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0, storage-access-framework

I am downloading file from server ,and saving to download folder in android ,accessing file path by following way to save

```
 Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

is depreceated in Android Q  ,So I have to use Storage access framework .

```
 fun downloadFile(url: String, originalFileName: String) {
    mDownloadDisposable.add(
            mRCloudRepository.downloadFile(url)
                    .flatMap(object : Function1<Response<ResponseBody>, Flowable<File>> {
                        override fun invoke(p1: Response<ResponseBody>): Flowable<File> {
                            return Flowable.create({
                                try {
                                    val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absoluteFile, originalFileName)
                                    val sink = file.sink().buffer() 
                                    sink.writeAll(p1.body()!!.source())
                                    sink.close()
                                    it.onNext(file)
                                    it.onComplete()
                                } catch (e: IOException) {
                                    e.printStackTrace()
                                    it.onError(e)
                                }
                            }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                        }

                    })
                    .subscribeOn(mIoScheduler)
                    .observeOn(mUiScheduler)
                    .subscribe(
                            {
                                cancelNotification()
                                val contentIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, NotificationBuilder.NOTIFICATION_DOWNLOAD_ID, getOpenFileIntent(it), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
                                NotificationBuilder.showDownloadedNotification(mContext!!, 2, "Downloaded $originalFileName ", "", contentIntent)
                            }, {
                        cancelNotification()
                        it.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    )
    )
}
```

Comment: Any problems? Any questions? Put all info in your post please.

Comment: @blackapps updated the question . I wanted to know how to use SAF to save files in Download folder .

Comment: You should put your problems and questions in your post. Not in comments. And certainly not only in the subject.

Comment: "I wanted to know how to use SAF to save files in Download folder" -- that is not possible, insofar as you do not control where the content gets stored. The user does. `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` would let the *user* control which of the *user's* locations on the *user's* device or the *user's* cloud services the *user* wants you to store the *user's* content. That may or may not be something named `Download`.

Comment: @CommonsWare .. thank you !  I am intrigued how gmail is saving attachments directly to download folders ?There isn't any kind of popup to select where to save attachments ? Are they not using SAF ?

Comment: My guess is that they are using `MediaStore`. That gained a new capability of working with `Downloads` in Android 10.

Comment: You should use `MediaStore` nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `DocumentFileCompat#createDownloadWithMediaStoreFallback()` in [Simple Storage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage):

```kotlin
val uri = DocumentFileCompat.createDownloadWithMediaStoreFallback(applicationContext, FileDescription(filename))
val output = uri?.openOutputStream(applicationContext)
val input = // get input stream from Response<ResponseBody>
// then, write input stream to output stream
```

In Android 10, accessing files in `Download` directory requires URI, instead of direct file path.